# AdaBoost ML algorithm python implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, adaboost

Is there anyone that has some ideas on how to implement the AdaBoost (Boostexter) algorithm in python?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a million Steve! In fact, your suggestion had some compatibility issues with MacOSX (a particular library was incompatible with the system) BUT it helped me find out a more interesting package : icsi.boost.macosx. I am just denoting that in case any Mac-eter finds it interesting!

Thank you again!

Tim

Comment: presumably you mean [this package](https://code.google.com/p/icsiboost/) which isn't a python module...

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if the [sdpy](http://code.google.com/p/sdpy/) project has an AdaBoost implementation. Specifically look at the `sdpy/cs/ml/cla/boosting.py` file.

Perhaps you can get some motivation from there.